# asp.net mvc pass Json object from view to controller

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, json

How can I pass JSON objec from AJAX success function to Controller?
I have this situation:

```
function order(model) {
    $.p({
        url: '@Url.Action("CompleteFrameBrandDetails", "PacCompleteFrame")',
        data: { item: model },
                        var pacModuleModel = {
                            CustomerNumber: model.Data.CustomerNumber,
                            Language: model.Data.Language,
                            Comission: model.Data.Comission,
                            GlassXml: model.Data.GlassXml,
                            Price: model.Data.Price,
                            ReadOnly: model.Data.ReadOnly,
                            Mode: model.Data.Mode,
                            IframeUrl: model.Data.Mode
                        };
                        var url = '@Url.Action("GlassCompleteFrameView", "PacModule", new { b2bXml = "__xml__" })';
                        $('#details-container').html(url.replace("__xml__", JSON.stringify(model.Data))); //"<h2>Loading Complete Frame Module. Please wait...</h2>"
                        window.location.href = url.replace("__xml__", JSONstringify(pacModuleModel)); //JSON.stringify(result.Data.GlassXml); JSON.stringify(result.Data)
                    }
                });

            } else {
                $.alert({
                    message: 'error while trying to load xml details'
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

I successfully get model in second Ajax call. But when passing to window.location I get null parameter in controller action. Here is my controller action code:

```
    public ActionResult GlassCompleteFrameView(JsonResult model)
    {
        return View("Glass", model);
    }
```

How should look like correct code to get my model from view to controller via javascript? Or should I use some other approach?

And bellow is my model:

```
public partial class PacModuleModel
{
    private PacPermissionModel permissionModel;


    public ModuleMode Mode { get; set; }
    public string IframeUrl { get; set; }
    public string CustomerNumber { get; set; }
    public bool ReadOnly { get; set; }
    public string GlassXml { get; set; }
    public double? Price { get; set; }
    public string Comission { get; set; }
    public PacPermissionModel Permissions
    {
        get
        {
            if (permissionModel == null)
            {
                permissionModel = new PacPermissionModel();
            }
            return permissionModel;
        }
    }
    public string Language { get; set; }
}
```

GlassCompleteFrame action:

```
    public ActionResult GlassCompleteFrame(string b2bXml)
    {
        string mode = "5";

        //If the Store isn't selected, redirect to HomePage
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_workContext.SelectedCustomerNumber))
        {
            return RedirectToRoute("HomePage");
        }
        else
        {
            PacModuleModel model = new PacModuleModel();
            model.CustomerNumber = _workContext.SelectedCustomerNumber;
            model.Language = _workContext.WorkingLanguage.UniqueSeoCode;
            model.Comission = "";
            model.GlassXml = b2bXml.Replace("\"", "\\\"");
            int index = b2bXml.IndexOf("<price>") + "<price>".Length;
            string p = b2bXml.Substring(index, b2bXml.IndexOf("</price>") - index);
            model.Price = Convert.ToDouble(p, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            model.ReadOnly = false;
            model.Mode = ModuleMode.ByProduct;
            model.IframeUrl = "http://ItkCompleteConfiEmbedded.aspx?lang=" + _workContext.WorkingLanguage.LanguageCulture;

            return new JsonResult()
            {
                Data = new
                {
                    Success = true,
                    Data = model
                }
            };
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried binding the JSON to your model (I'm assuming your JSON matches your model)?

```
public ActionResult GlassCompleteFrameView(PacModuleModel model)
{
    return View("Glass", model);
}
```

Here is an introduction to [binding JSON to a model](http://codeforcoffee.org/asp-net-mvc-intro-to-mvc-using-binding-json-objects-to-models/).

Comment: WooHoo thank you for the answer. Yes my JSON matches to my model. I chanhe type of parameter like you suggested but I still get model = null. Something else is missing or it is not ok, but i dont see what :( Thank you also for the article. I hope that I will figured out. If you have some more hints how to solve this I will be gratefull.

Comment: @Korl could you add a sample of your JSON to your question?

Comment: If I pass simple string then works, even vith JSON object like model.Data.Language but not with model.Data.GlassXml :( GlassXml is pretty long. Maybe is this cause of problem. I don't have idea. Please help.

Comment: WooHoo I added my JSON object in my question. Please see last function.

Comment: Your JSON has to have the same properties as your model for the automatic binding to work.  If you look at the example link you can see that in JavaScript the author builds a model and then posts this to the action method.  The model in the action method has the same name as the JSON object, so auto binding knows to match, name with model.name, age with mode.age.

Comment: I add now JSON in Ajax function like this:

Comment: Please look updated question in order function. I think that problem is in window.location.href. I am not shure if I bind object correct.

Answer (score 0):

I use Session variable to get model in GlassCompleteFrameView(PacModuleModel model) and works perfect. I set it in public ActionResult GlassCompleteFrame(string b2bXml) and use it like bellow.

```
public ActionResult GlassCompleteFrameView(PacModuleModel model)
{
    model = Session["xml"] as PacModuleModel;
    return View("Glass", model);
}
```